# How do I directly make an val binding to an option value in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

`val SOME i = Int.fromString e`

I have a line like this on my code and smlnj shows me this warning

```
vm.sml:84.7-84.32 Warning: binding not exhaustive
          SOME i = ...
```

Is this bad practice? Should I use a function to handle the option or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just working on a small script you'll run once, it's not necessarily bad practice: If `Int.fromString e` fails (and returns `NONE` instead of `SOME _`), then the value binding will fail and an exception will be raised to the appropriate handler (or the program will exit, if ther is no handler). To disable this warning, you can run the top-level statement (for SML-NJ 110.96): `Control.MC.bindNonExhaustiveWarn := false;`.

As an alternative approach, you could throw a custom exception:

```
val i =
  case Int.fromString e
    of SOME i => i
     | NONE => raise Fail ("Expected string value to be parseable as an int; got: " ^ e)
```

The exception message should be written in a way that's appropriate to the provenance of the `e` value. (If `e` comes from command-line input, the program should tell the user that a number was expected there; if `e` comes from a file, the program should tell the user which file is formatted incorrectly and where the formatting error was found.)

As yet another alternative: If your program is meant to be long-running and builds up a lot of state, it wouldn't be very user-friendly if the program crashed as soon as the user entered an ill-formed string on the command line. (The user would be quite sad in this case, as all the state they built up in the program would have been lost.) In this case, you could repeatedly read from stdin until the user types in input that can be parsed as an int. This is incidentally more-or-less what the SML/NJ REPL does: instead of something like `val SOME parsedProgram = SMLofNJ.parse (getUserInput ())`, it would want to do something like:

```
fun getNextParsedProgram () =
  case SMLofNJ.parse (getUserInput ())
    of NONE => (print "ERROR: failed to parse\n"; getNextParsedProgram ())
     | SOME parsedProgram => parsedProgram
```

In summary,

1. For a short-lived script or a script you don't intend on running often, turning off the warning is a fine option.
2. For a program where it's unexpected that `e` would be an unparseable string, you could raise a custom exception that explains what went wrong and how the user can fix it.
3. For longer-lived programs where better error handling is desired, you should respect the `NONE` case by pattern-matching on the result of `fromString`, which forces you to come up with some sort of error-handling behavior.